# how to display/print/echo/console.log etc. value(s) of Elements array(s)

Tags: arrays, three.js, element

so, how would I find the workaround for the following

```
s.getDescendants()=[THREE.Light,THREE.Mesh,...]

//what I want [THREE.Light,THREE.Mesh,...]
//what I've gotten [object Object,object Object,...]
```

I'm new to THREE.js,

for further explanation email me `luisfernandoavila@outlook.com`

Comment: kindly don't list your personal information here, and keep the question related discussion on SO only as it might help someone else too